# C++ random number between 2 numbers reset

Tags: c++, random, numbers

The function below runs, but always returns the same numbers each time I run the program.  Is there a way to generate random numbers that are different each time I run the program?

```
int getrand(int min,int max){
 int rnum = rand()%(max-min)+min;
 return rnum;  
}
```

Comment: You do realize that your code is problematic for 2 reasons? First, `max` and `min` conflict with #defines and functions in some libraries/APIs, and second, `%` causes a non-uniform distribution, unless the modulus is (accidentially) a power of 2. The "correct" way to generate random numbers in some range is to generate random numbers and reject the ones that are outside the range. About the actual question, you want to `srand` once at program startup.

Comment: There can be no macros named `max` and `min` anywhere, since these are the names of functions in the standard library; if such macros exist, you can't use the standard library.

Comment: @Damon While it's try that you have to reject some numbers to avoid bias, you can't just reject those outside of the range; if the range is [0, 1], you're going to have to reject an awful lot of numbers.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The Windows API is one example of an API where `min` and `max` _are_ macros (unless you explicitly disable them). Yes, they conflict with template classes in `<algorithm>` which in fact is an example of "some libraries" that have them as functions. What exactly is not right with what I said? A variable called `min` or `max` _is_ problematic for this precise reason.

Comment: @Damon The Windows API doesn't define them if you use the correct compiler invocation (although admittedly, it shouldn't define them, period).  There's absolutely nothing wrong with using `min` and `max` as local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution to randomize once would be:

```
int getrand(int min, int max) {
  static bool init = false;

  if (!init) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    init = true;
  }

  return rand()%(max-min)+min; 
}
```

Comment: using an int for a boolean in C++, really? Also, this could reinitialize the global random generator for other sequences that don't expect this to happen.

Comment: change it to bool (was in my µC World)

Comment: Gotta agree with @KillianDS, it's much better to seed the generator at one spot in program initialization rather than allowing it to be set multiple times; if they all use `time(NULL)` as the seed you'll get a repeating sequence most of the time.

Answer (score 6):

You might like to use the high-quality standard library random number generation facilities:

```
#include <random>

typedef std::mt19937 rng_type;
std::uniform_int_distribution<rng_type::result_type> udist(min, max);

rng_type rng;

int main()
{
  // seed rng first:
  rng_type::result_type const seedval = 4; // or implement a good get_seed()?
  rng.seed(seedval);

  rng_type::result_type random_number = udist(rng);

  return random_number;
}
```

Comment: @user1054513: that's just an example. You have to provide your own seed value. Use `4` if you can't think of any.

Comment: @user1054513 that is because it is a generic placeholder for a function that provides a seed to the generator. Very often some time function is used for this purpose as the time is likely to be different every time you run it.

Comment: @Kerrek: but that will not help to "generate random numbers that are different each time I run the program"!

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Just for you, use `std::time(NULL)` :-)

Answer (score 2):

try with this:

```
/* initialize random seed: */
  srand ( time(NULL) );
```

somewhere when your program start ( *absolutely* not in your getrand() function ). This will force the generator to start each time with a different seed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to call `srand`.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo random number generators need to be "seeded" before you use them; the default seed is the same every time, so you get the same sequence.

Typically you use something like `srand(time(NULL))`, but this fails if you run the program again within a second.

It's also good to use up a random number or two after seeding, since the first few values are highly correlated with the seed itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate the seed. Check out `srand`. Also, try boost if you want:

```
boost::lagged_fibonacci607 base_prng(seed);
boost::variate_generator<boost::lagged_fibonacci607&,boost::uniform_smallint<> > prng(base_prng,boost::uniform_smallint<>(min,max))
```